java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider androidx.startup.InitializationProvider: androidx.startup.StartupException
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.hari.solutionhub, PID: 8200
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider androidx.startup.InitializationProvider: androidx.startup.StartupException: androidx.startup.StartupException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/lifecycle/ReportFragment$ActivityInitializationListener;
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7770)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:7276)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6983)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2236)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
                                                                                                    Caused by: androidx.startup.StartupException: androidx.startup.StartupException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/lifecycle/ReportFragment$ActivityInitializationListener;
                                                                                                        at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.doInitialize(AppInitializer.java:187)
                                                                                                        at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.discoverAndInitialize(AppInitializer.java:238)
                                                                                                        at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.discoverAndInitialize(AppInitializer.java:206)
                                                                                                        at androidx.startup.InitializationProvider.onCreate(InitializationProvider.java:45)
                                                                                                        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2619)
                                                                                                        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2589)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7765)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:7276) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6983) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2236) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971) 
                                                                                                    Caused by: androidx.startup.StartupException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/lifecycle/ReportFragment$ActivityInitializationListener;
                                                                                                        at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.doInitialize(AppInitializer.java:187)
                                                                                                        at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.doInitialize(AppInitializer.java:173)
                                                                                                        at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.discoverAndInitialize(AppInitializer.java:238) 
                                                                                                        at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.discoverAndInitialize(AppInitializer.java:206) 
                                                                                                        at androidx.startup.InitializationProvider.onCreate(InitializationProvider.java:45) 
                                                                                                        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2619) 
                                                                                                        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2589) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7765) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:7276) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6983) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2236) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971) 
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/lifecycle/ReportFragment$ActivityInitializationListener;
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleInitializer.create(ProcessLifecycleInitializer.kt:37)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleInitializer.create(ProcessLifecycleInitializer.kt:25)
                                                                                                        at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.doInitialize(AppInitializer.java:180)
                                                                                                        at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.doInitialize(AppInitializer.java:173) 
                                                                                                        at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.discoverAndInitialize(AppInitializer.java:238) 
                                                                                                        at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.discoverAndInitialize(AppInitializer.java:206) 
                                                                                                        at androidx.startup.InitializationProvider.onCreate(InitializationProvider.java:45) 
                                                                                                        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2619) 
                                                                                                        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2589) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7765) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:7276) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6983) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2236) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971) 
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.lifecycle.ReportFragment$ActivityInitializationListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~mi0tgFctKyWMhWp6RdCBdA==/com.hari.solutionhub-32i-1skBzq58WrlGhQvzYQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~mi0tgFctKyWMhWp6RdCBdA==/com.hari.solutionhub-32i-1skBzq58WrlGhQvzYQ==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
                                                                                                        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleInitializer.create(ProcessLifecycleInitializer.kt:37) 
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleInitializer.create(ProcessLifecycleInitializer.kt:25) 
                                                                                                        at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.doInitialize(AppInitializer.java:180) 
                                                                                                        at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.doInitialize(AppInitializer.java:173) 
                                                                                                        at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.discoverAndInitialize(AppInitializer.java:238) 
                                                                                                        at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.discoverAndInitialize(AppInitializer.java:206) 
                                                                                                        at androidx.startup.InitializationProvider.onCreate(InitializationProvider.java:45) 
                                                                                                        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2619) 
                                                                                                        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2589) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7765) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:7276) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6983) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2236) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971) 
2024-05-11 12:26:55.992  2078-3346  OpenGLRenderer          com....android.googlequicksearchbox  E  Unable to match the desired swap behavior.
2024-05-11 12:26:56.058  2983-3021  OpenGLRenderer          com...le.android.apps.nexuslauncher  E  Unable to match the desired swap behavior.
2024-05-11 12:27:00.973   610-1886  TaskPersister           system_server                        E  File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
2024-05-11 12:27:09.273  5389-7992  WakeLock                com.google.android.gms.persistent    E  GCM_HB_ALARM release without a matched acquire!
2024-05-11 12:28:40.036   610-775   WifiStaIfaceAidlImpl    system_server                        E  installApfPacketFilter failed with service-specific exception: android.os.ServiceSpecificException:  (code 4)
2024-05-11 12:31:59.460  5389-7992  WakeLock                com.google.android.gms.persistent    E  GCM_HB_ALARM release without a matched acquire!
2024-05-11 12:35:36.657   610-775   WifiStaIfaceAidlImpl    system_server                        E  installApfPacketFilter failed with service-specific exception: android.os.ServiceSpecificException:  (code 4)
2024-05-11 12:36:49.810  5389-7992  WakeLock                com.google.android.gms.persistent    E  GCM_HB_ALARM release without a matched acquire!
2024-05-11 12:37:51.876   610-8252  GnssPsdsDownloader      system_server                        E  No Long-Term PSDS servers were specified in the GnssConfiguration
2024-05-11 12:41:39.994  5389-8116  WakeLock                com.google.android.gms.persistent    E  GCM_HB_ALARM release without a matched acquire!
2024-05-11 12:43:32.647   610-775   WifiStaIfaceAidlImpl    system_server                        E  installApfPacketFilter failed with service-specific exception: android.os.ServiceSpecificException:  (code 4)
2024-05-11 12:46:30.232  5389-8236  WakeLock                com.google.android.gms.persistent    E  GCM_HB_ALARM release without a matched acquire!
2024-05-11 12:51:06.180   610-775   WifiStaIfaceAidlImpl    system_server                        E  installApfPacketFilter failed with service-specific exception: android.os.ServiceSpecificException:  (code 4)

I am creating an app from github.
How to solve it?

It's simple as Android is forcing java devs to use kotlin. just add kotlin and do not use it (doesn't even look like a normal programing language).

I had the same issue with my java project after upgrading androidx.lifecycle dependencies from version 2.7.0 to 2.8.0
Issue was resolved by adding id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' in build.gradle (app)
plugins {
...
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
...
}

An explanation or elaboration as to why/how this arises, and why your solution fixes the problem would be helpful.

I'm not a specialist at all and my English is limited . but I guess that with the version 2.8 of androidx.lifecycle dependencies, the java project need more kotlin support.Hence the idea of adding full kotlin gradle-plugin.
- In project build.gradle add
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.9.22"
(For kotlin_version see kotlin plugin version in android studio : Tools->Kotlin)
- In app build.gradle add
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

This helped me with the issue, I've found this link which contains some other related information as we

The problem happens when upgrading androidx lifecycle to 2.8.x
make sure you use the following
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.7.0'

and if your build.gradle looks like this
implementation libs.lifecycle.livedata.ktx
implementation libs.lifecycle.viewmodel.ktx

you should open the project structure dialog and downgrade the version from the dialog -> dependencies -> app
spend more than 4 hours on this issue. good luck
